ApplicationResourceBundle (.arb) JSON schema wanted
Context
I'm about to localize my old app and at the moment I'm working on simple Python script to parse my source code for L("blabla") constructions, and extend existing .arb template with new stubs.
I also hope to adopt this script to be a tooling for my flutter app. I want to use basic intl flutter package. So with this script I want to handle in-code localized string calls and also extend existing .arb files. So it will act somewhat similar to intl_translation but in a simpler way.
Question
.arb seem pretty much like a JSON files. So may be there is JSON schema somewhere for this format?
Thanks!
P.S.: So far I'm reading its spec and trying to convert it into the set of pydantic classes model, which (as I hope) will produce some sort of recovered JSON schema for these files.

P.S.: I have created very primitive pydantic classes model, let me guys know if you're interested, and I'll post it as an answer.
